# How to write test case for vscode.window.showInformationMessage()?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

in vs code extension, I need to write test case that on execution of the command, the information message display and the text on write assetion for the information message  but unable to see anywhere how to do that.

here is the extension code

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "css-color-collector" is now active!');

    const command = 'css-color-collector.init';
    const commandHandler = () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from css color collector!');
    };
    let disposableInit = vscode.commands.registerCommand(command, commandHandler);
    context.subscriptions.push(disposableInit)
}
```

and here I want to write test case for above

```js
import * as assert from 'assert';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

suite('Extension Test Suite', () => {
    

    suite('extension setup', () => {

        test('display message on init command', () => {
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('css-color-collector.init');
            // How to validate the message content here?
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass callback returning your text into the commnad this way:

```
const commandHandler = (callback: (t: string) => void) =>
{
    const text = 'Hello World from css color collector!';
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(text);
    callback(text);
};
```

and then get it:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('css-color-collector.init', t =>
{
    console.log(t);
});
```

another way is returning your text from command:

```
const commandHandler = async () =>
{
    const text = 'Hello World from css color collector!';
    // put 'await' before this if you want wait for message been closed
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(text);
    return text;
};

// and then
const result = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('css-color-collector.init');
console.log(result);
```